# Rails - options_from_collection_for_select - Display other fields based on what is currently highlighted in dropdown?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got a options_from_collection_for_select call that is returning the correct collection.  Many of the records have a blank value being displayed for the name.  Is there a way to display other attributes of the currently highlighted record in the dropdown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not limited to the attributes of the objects as represented in the database, so you can simply define an alternative method in your model that returns name/an alternative attribute if name is nil, like:

```
class User
  def name_or_alternative
    name || alternative
  end
end
```

and then call this method from your `options_from_collection_for_select` instead.